# Core Data Reset keeping same schema in swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I am currently working with core data in swift and i want to reset my core data to blank but don't want to change the schema. 
Actually the problem is i am getting some data and displaying it in table view and after i logout and login with other account the old data is still there from previous account so i think i need to reset my core data.

I need solution in swift. Thanks in advance

I am trying this

```
class func deleteAllManagedObjects() {
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("some string", withExtension: "mom")
    let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)

    for entityName in mom.entitiesByName.keys {
        let fr = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName as String)
        let a = Utility.managedObjectContext().executeFetchRequest(fr, error: nil) as [NSManagedObject]
        for mo in a {
            Utility.managedObjectContext().deleteObject(mo)
        }
    }

    Utility.managedObjectContext().save(nil)
}
```

Comment: Easiest way will be to close and release the MOC and the Persistent store, delete the file, and then recreate it.

Comment: delete the file**S**. `.sqlite`, `.sqlite-wal`, `.sqlite-shm`

Comment: @TomHarrington the answers were given in objective-c

Comment: @ManuGupta All of the method names are the same, and the steps are all the same. You would call the same methods, in the same order, with the same arguments, just with slightly different syntax.